# Is there a better method than onMouseExited that detects when it exits no matter how fast it moves?

Tags: java, javafx

Can someone tell me how I can do so that an animation is made in a pane when the mouse is over said pane and make another when it is the opposite? I tried using the onMouseEntered and onMouseExited methods, with the first one there was no problem, however if we remove the mouse very quickly or abruptly, the program will not detect the exit of the mouse and therefore the animation will not be executed, can someone help me to solve this bug? please

first add 2 methods to an events from the scene builder for the pane, these are said methods

```
public void scale1 () {
        double currentScaleX = pane1.getScaleX();
        double currentScaleY = pane1.getScaleY();
        
        if(currentScaleX ==1.0 && currentScaleY ==1.0) {
        
            scale.setNode(pane1);
            scale.setDuration(Duration.millis(100));
            scale.setByX(0.75);
            scale.setByY(0.75);
            scale.play();
            
        }   
    }

public void scale1Re () {
        double currentScaleX = pane1.getScaleX();
        double currentScaleY = pane1.getScaleY();

        if(currentScaleX >1.0 && currentScaleY >1.0) {
            scale.setNode(pane1);
            scale.setDuration(Duration.millis(100));
            scale.setByX(-0.75);
            scale.setByY(-0.75);
            scale.play();
            
        }
    }
```

However, when executed it works, but if we move the mouse very quickly, it will not detect the change and sometimes it will only execute the first method[It is not seen in the screenshot, but my mouse is out of the pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH0kd.png)

I even tried to make a mouselistener class in my controller class so that it detects when the mouse is out of the pane or something and automatically executes the second method, but I think I did it wrong

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        pane1.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                Bounds bounds = principalPane.getBoundsInParent();
                if (bounds.contains(mouseEvent.getSceneX(), mouseEvent.getSceneY())) {
                    scale1Re();
                }
            }
        });

        
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: As @kleopatra has noted, there's not enough code here for a real answer.  I'm going to guess, though, that it's not the MouseEvent that being missed, but the fact that you just have one ScaleTransition, it takes 100ms, and it's already running when the mouse exits.  So it doesn't run again.  You could change the setByX/setByY to setToX/setToY and use values of 1.75 and 1.00 which would allow you to cancel the running transition and then restart it with new parameters.  Alternatively, you could create a new transition each time and figure out how to queue them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the MouseExited that's being missed, it's the in progress transitions that cause the problem.

Two things need to be done.  First, the ScaleTransition has be set to absolutes targets, so setToX() not setByX().  Second, change the play() to playFromStart().  Like so...

```
class MouseOverExample : Application() {
   override fun start(stage: Stage) {
      stage.scene = Scene(createContent())
      stage.show()
   }

   private fun createContent(): Region = HBox(40.0).apply {
      children += listOf(animatedPane(100.0), animatedPane(500.0), animatedPane(1200.0))
      padding = Insets(40.0)
   }

   private fun animatedPane(transitionDuration: Double): Region = StackPane().apply {
      children += Label("H").apply { style = "-fx-font-size: 40px;" }
      style = "-fx-border-color: blue; -fx-border-width: 5px;"
      padding = Insets(20.0)
      val transition: ScaleTransition = ScaleTransition().also {
         it.node = this
         it.duration = Duration(transitionDuration)
      }
      onMouseEntered = EventHandler {
         with(transition) {
            toX = 1.5
            toY = 1.5
            playFromStart()
         }
      }
      onMouseExited = EventHandler {
         with(transition) {
            toX = 1.0
            toY = 1.0
            playFromStart()
         }
      }
   }
}

fun main() {
   Application.launch(MouseOverExample::class.java)
}
```

This is Kotlin, but it should be easy enough to figure out.

This gives three Panes, each with a transition associated with it, and the durations are all different so that you can see how mouse speed has an impact.

At 100ms, a partial grow followed by a shrink looks just fine.  At 1200ms, if the mouse exits and the grow transition stops after, say, 100ms then it will still take 1200ms to shrink back to the original size, which is kind of goofy.  But in every case the Pane goes back to its original size no matter how fast you sweep the mouse through it.

Comment: I guess this was an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) then.